# How to install and use Scrapy within a TERMINAL opended within Visual Sudio Code under Windows 10?

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, scrapy, window

within the TERMINAL window having the prompt
PS C:\Rolf\py_scripts
I have run

```
pip install scrapy
```

I got the message
Successfully installed Automat-20.2.0 PyDispatcher-2.0.5  ...
therefore I presume, that the installion was succesfull
but

```
scrapy startproject sainsburys
```

fails with the message "command scrapy is unknown."

I've seen that there is a "scrapy.exe" somewhere on the harddisk of my computer I think the directory where Scrapy resides is not included in PATH.

My question: How do I have to install scrapy not only that the modules can be used with "import" in python but also the scrapy command can be used in a powershell window opende withon VSCode?

For sake of completeness: I do not need (and would prefer not to use) virtual environments

Comment: ...then edit your real environment. Add the location of `scrapy.exe` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. (I should have know myself) and it makes even possible to run scrapy in any cmd/powershell window, as long as I know where my the scrapy project resides

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip install -t floderPath scrapy #floderPath is your python package path` to install scrapy to your python package.

Of course, you can use `pip show scrapy` to see the location of scrapy and add it to PATH environment variable.